# File not found error with mysqlimport

Tags: mysql, import

I'm setting up a local database for gene annotation following the instructions on [this page](http://blast2go.bioinfo.cipf.es/localgodb). They provide an .sql file to create some MySQL table structures (step 4) and several data files to populate the tables (steps 5-7). I've completed the setup process through step 5, but I am getting errors at step 6. What's unnerving is that the error I'm getting is different based on which directory I execute the `mysqlimport` command from.

```
standage@farnsworth:~$ mysqlimport -u wendel2go -p --fields-terminated-by='\t' b2g Desktop/gene2accession 
Enter password: 
mysqlimport: Error: 13, Can't get stat of '/var/lib/mysql/Desktop/gene2accession' (Errcode: 2), when using table: gene2accession
standage@farnsworth:~$ cd Desktop/
standage@farnsworth:~/Desktop$ mysqlimport -u wendel2go -p --fields-terminated-by='\t' b2g gene2accession 
Enter password: 
mysqlimport: Error: 29, File '/var/lib/mysql/b2g/gene2accession' not found (Errcode: 2), when using table: gene2accession
```

I'm not getting very informative results when I'm googling this error. Any ideas?

**Update**: I still get an error when I use the full path of the file, but the file not found is different now.

```
standage@farnsworth:~$ mysqlimport -u root -p --fields-terminated-by='\t' b2g /home/standage/Desktop/gene2accession 
Enter password: 
mysqlimport: Error: 29, File '/home/standage/Desktop/gene2accession' not found (Errcode: 13), when using table: gene2accession
standage@farnsworth:~$ list /home/standage/Desktop/gene2accession 
-rw-r--r-- 1 standage standage 1.6G 2010-12-01 14:31 /home/standage/Desktop/gene2accession
```

The file exists, and it's not a permissions issue.

Comment: BTW, I'm running Ubuntu 10.04 32 bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the full path to the file:

```
mysqlimport -u wendel2go -p --fields-terminated-by='\t' b2g /home/username/Desktop/gene2accession
```

Replace "username" with your user name.

Comment: I get the `Error: 29` again when I use the full path.

Comment: @Daniel: Three things to try: Add `--local` to your `mysqlimport` command. If that doesn't work, try `chgrp mysql ~/Desktop/gene2accession; chmod g+r ~/Desktop/gene2accession` and try your command again. If that doesn't work, try moving the file from `Desktop` to `/var/lib/mysql` and use `./gene2accession` or `gene2accession` as your last argument.

Comment: Using the `--local` option worked. Thanks!